# How to See the Contents of Windows library (*.lib)

Tags: windows, static-libraries, libraries

I have a binary file - Windows static library (*.lib).
Is there a simple way to find out names of the functions and their interface from that library ?

Something similar to `emfar` and `elfdump` utilities (on Linux systems) ?

Comment: Note: The command prompt specific to .NET comes with the Visual Studio editions but not with the Express edition. From:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9f4b8961-63eb-4062-bf3c-12f0126f0e80/how-to-get-visual-studio-command-prompt?forum=Vsexpressvb

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about a static library, `DUMPBIN /SYMBOLS` shows the functions and data objects in the library.  If you're talking about an import library (a `.lib` used to refer to symbols exported from a DLL), then you want `DUMPBIN /EXPORTS`.

Note that for functions linked with the "C" binary interface, this still won't get you return values, parameters, or calling convention.  That information isn't encoded in the `.lib` at all; you have to know that ahead of time (via prototypes in header files, for example) in order to call them correctly.

For functions linked with the C++ binary interface, the calling convention and arguments are encoded in the exported name of the function (also called "name mangling").  `DUMPBIN /SYMBOLS` will show you both the "mangled" function name as well as the decoded set of parameters.

Comment: Both /SYMBOLS and /EXPORTS don't work nowadays. I have to use /ALL with a |more pipe to see all functions in the .lib file.

Comment: @user5280911 `dumpbin /symbols` worked fine for me today on Win 10 with VS 2019 developer command prompt on a static library `.lib` file, why do you say it doesn't work these days?

Comment: You can use `/OUT:filename` in order to export the output to a file

Comment: What is DUMPBIN ? Where is it ?

Comment: Dumpbin is a command line app that's installed alongside VS. From within VS you can access it via Tools > Command Line > Developer Command Prompt. Then type "dumpbin"

Comment: `dumpbin /exports` does not show `__imp__calloc` in `ucrt.lib` for example (although the reference arises in user code), `dumpbin /linkermember:1` does show it ...   Hint: Use `| find /i "calloc"` to filter the symbols you search for.

Comment: FWIW `dumpbin` appears **not** to be available in the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 137):

Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt

```
dumpbin /ARCHIVEMEMBERS openssl.x86.lib
```

or

```
lib /LIST openssl.x86.lib
```

or **just open it with 7-zip** :) its an AR archive

Comment: Cool trick with 7-zip there seems to be  two .txt files there what do they mean?

Comment: These both just list a load of DLL names. `dumpbin /exports` lists the actual symbols.

Answer (score 22):

I wanted a tool like `ar t libfile.a` in unix.
The windows equivalent is `lib.exe /list libfile.lib`.

Comment: Yes lib will (only) show the obj files; it will not show the functions and data in the obj files.

Answer (score 20):

"dumpbin -exports" works for dll, but sometimes may not work for lib. For lib we can use "dumpbin -linkermember" or just "dumpbin -linkermember:1".

Answer (score 16):

LIB.EXE is the librarian for VS

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ykb2k5f(VS.80).aspx

(like libtool on Unix)

Answer (score 15):

[DUMPBIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=vs-2019) /EXPORTS  Will get most of that information and hitting MSDN will get the rest.

Get one of the Visual Studio packages; C++

Answer (score 5):

Like it can be seen in other answers you'll have to open a Developer Command Prompt offered in your version of Visual Studio to have `dumpbin.exe` in your execution path. Otherwise, you can set the necessary environment variables by hand.

`dumpbin /EXPORTS yourlibrary.lib` will usually show just a tiny list of symbols. In many cases, it won't show the functions the library exports.

`dumpbin /SYMBOLS /EXPORTS yourlibrary.lib` will show that symbols, but also an incredibly huge amount of other symbos. So, you got to filter them, possibly with a pipe to `findstr` (if you want a MS-Windows tool), or `grep`.

Searching the `Static` keyword using one of these tools seems to be a good hint.

Answer (score 4):

1) Open a Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 (or whatever version you have on your machine)(It should be located under: Start menu --> All programs --> Visual Studio 2017 (or whatever version you have on your machine) --> Visual Studio Tools 
 --> Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017.

2) Enter the following command:

`dumpbin /EXPORTS my_lib_name.lib`