# How can you examine lib files?

Tags: cvi, visual-studio-2010

I have a List of 390 Libraries and need to port a software from lab CVI to Visual C. Those dependencies are killing me.

I cant import all of them, that would be overkill - and not all of them are unique and/or can be loaded at all.

Is there an easy way to determine what calls a lib file takes? 
Are there any editors for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to See the Contents of Windows library (\*.lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305287/how-to-see-the-contents-of-windows-library-lib)

Comment: Thanks @StayOnTarget - back in the day I was way to cautious with old code and tried to preserve it. The way out ended up as a combination of intense legacy refactoring, unit testing and massive code base rewrites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft librarian program LIB.EXE allows you to examine library contents, assuming you are asking about static libraries. It's part of the VC++ distribution, or at least it used to be - I don't use VC++ any more. These are the options available:

```
Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 6.00.8168
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1992-1998. All rights reserved.

usage: LIB [options] [files]

   options:

      /CONVERT
      /DEBUGTYPE:CV
      /DEF[:filename]
      /EXPORT:symbol
      /EXTRACT:membername
      /INCLUDE:symbol
      /LIBPATH:dir
      /LINK50COMPAT
      /LIST[:filename]
      /MACHINE:{ALPHA|ARM|IX86|MIPS|MIPS16|MIPSR41XX|PPC|SH3|SH4}
      /NAME:filename
      /NODEFAULTLIB[:library]
      /NOLOGO
      /OUT:filename
      /REMOVE:membername
      /SUBSYSTEM:{NATIVE|WINDOWS|CONSOLE|WINDOWSCE|POSIX}[,#[.##]]
      /VERBOSE
```

Comment: Yes, i found it "\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin" - Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

There is one other thing you might consider doing to reduce the amount of content that you import with a static library.  In CVI, open the header file corresponding to the .lib/.dll that you are using.  Save this file to a different `name.h`.

Again, in the editor, edit that file to include only the exported functions you would like to use.  **Caution:** *Do not edit out functions that may be called by the functions you intend to keep.*  Once satisfied you have a file representative of what you want, click anywhere in the new `name.h` file (to make sure it is the active file)  and use the menus at the top of the workspace to select *Options->Generate DLL Import Library...*
A popup file selection dialog box will appear.  Using that dialog, navigate to the `.dll` corresponding to the `.lib` file you want to generate.  If successful, a new `name.lib` will be created containing only the exported functions you want.

One additional side benefit of limiting the number of exports is that it will help to avoid *[COFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF)* incompatibility problems sometimes seen when mixing libraries created in different environments.