# Interfacing between LABWINDOWS and dSPACE(MRET)

Tags: labwindows

I have to make an interface between dSPACE(MRET) and Labwindows CVI for my test automation. All my test scripts are already in Labwindows which i want to run in dSPACE. can any of you please tell how to make this interfacing using some DLL file or any other way?

I suspect that dSPACE never provides any interfacing DLL to Labwindows.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is vague, more specific information will help get more specific answers.

Regarding

> *I suspect that dSPACE never provides any interfacing DLL to Labwindows*

They might, [look here](http://www.dspace.com/en/inc/home/products/sw/impsw/compilers.cfm) for instance (quick google search)

LabWindows/CVI should be able to link and build to any C compatible API.  If there is a header file, you can even guarantee a COFF compatible (and CVI compatible) .lib file to make things easier. Creating the .lib from a header file with an associated .dll is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461389/how-can-you-examine-lib-files/5760753#5760753).

If dSPACE(MRET) has the ability to call from other libraries, then porting CVI functions, into a .dll is a good way to go.  Look [here](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/EC2ECA974F8763D586256929006D17D7) ,[here](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/nisearchservlet?nistype=psrelcon&nid=11107&lang=en&q=FQL:((nilangs:en))%20AND%20((phwebnt:1801)%20OR%20(phwebnt:1802))%20%20AND%20(nicontenttype:productmanual)%20AND%20(docstatus:current)RANK%20nilangs:en&title=NI%20LabWindows%E2%84%A2/CVI%20for%20Windows%20Manuals) and [here](http://www.tau.ac.il/~roichman/CVI/manual.pdf) (starting bottom of page 2.6).