# Unresolved external symbol when linking my library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, static-libraries, static-linking

I've compiled my own library file(.lib) with VS2010, but when I try to reference it like

```
#pragma comment(lib,"path/to/lib.lib")
```

I keep getting unresolved external symbols...What am I doing wrong?
the #pragma comment(lib, "*.lib") worked for any library so far, and I also tried linking it under settings, no succes.

Comment: Use `dumpbin` on your .lib file. You can run it from a visual studio command prompt. Check that the symbols you are expecting are actually visible in the library, then report back!

Comment: to:cli_hlt yes I have, I even tried using \\ and \, even typing the path wrong(which gave me file not found)
@Rook how do I use this? (actualy the first .lib I created)

Comment: @user1126068: either fire up a visual studio command prompt and run `dumpbin` from there, or search for it (on my machine it is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\dumpbin.exe`). Now you can run something like `dumpbin /ALL mylib.lib > symbols.txt` and open up the result in a text editor and search though.

Comment: Well to run dumpbin I had to copy mspdb100.dll, then I tried running the compiler again and now I got:
Program database manager mismatch; please check your installation

Answer (score 3):

1) Open a VS command console (Tools/Visual Studio Command Prompt).

2) Use `cd` command to change to the directory containing the library in question.

3) Enter:

```
dumpbin /all my_lib_name.lib > lib.txt
```

replacing `my_lib_name.lib` with the name of your library.
(You'll want to write the output to a text file `lib.txt` for large libraries)

4) Open this newly created `lib.txt` to view the contents of the library.
More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305287/how-to-see-the-contents-of-windows-library-lib).

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Two directories.

   - First contained library that fails
   - Second contains binary directory with compilator (For me its C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC)
2. Copy mspdb*.dll(from first directory) to directory with library
3. Open cmd.exe in library directory
4. Write "%FIRST_DIRECTORY/bin/dumpbin.exe" /ALL library.lib > lib.txt
   (For example i am writed "*C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\dumpbin.exe" /ALL MyTestLibrary.lib > lib.txt*)
5. Search for methods that you want(by class name or method name)

If you dont found - developer dont writed it. OR **that methods implementations are inline**

If second - you should told IDE whereis source.
*BTW remember, no methods in library-compiling project, that accessable through user headers could be inline. All you can do to optimise speed - fastcall.*