# How to find out functions missing from a library, but which are present in the exposed header file released along with the library?

Tags: c, shared-libraries

We have a legacy library implementation and associated exposed header files. Recently we found that, some of the functions in the exposed header file, don't have corresponding definitions in the library implementation.

We want to check if there could be some more such functions. Is there any easier way of doing this rather than sifting through each and every API present in header and then checking if there is a definition for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate C source from the header (Perl is a way to go!) that calls all the functions and try to compile it. Linker will complain about missing functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create the ABI dump file by the [abi-compliance-checker](http://lvc.github.io/abi-compliance-checker/) tool:

```
abi-compliance-checker -lib NAME -dump DESC.xml
```

*DESC.xml* file is the following:

```
<version>
    1.0
</version>

<headers>
    /path(s)/to/headers
</headers>

<libs>
    /path(s)/to/libraries
</libs>
```

The resulting ABI dump file will contain the information you need about symbols declared in header files (`SymbolInfo`) and symbols exported by shared libraries (`Symbols`).

You can also generate ABI dump in the xml format by adding `--xml` option.

Answer (score 0):

If this is C, you can do something like:

```
printf("", /* insert all functions here */);
```

That should pass them all as function pointers to `printf`. The ones that do not exist should show up as linker errors.

(In C++, you would have to list overloads explicitly, which makes it a bit more difficult.)

Comment: But I have to pass valid arguments to all the functions which may be hectic ofcourse creating dummy arguments.

Comment: @Sibrajas, not if you pass the functions as function pointers. If you want to be explicit, you can use something like: `printf("", &mylibfunc1, &mylibfunc2 /*more functions go here*/);`

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to use `ctags` to generate a list of identifiers from the header file then use `ar`, `emfar` or `elfdump` in Unix or `lib.exe` or `dumpbin.exe` in Windows (see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305287/how-to-see-the-contents-of-windows-library-lib)) to dump a list of identifiers from the library and then sort and `diff` the two lists.