# How to create a .def file containing all functions and variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I have a library and I want to get all mangled function and variable names. I will put those names in a .def file to import them in another project.
I'm programming in c++ using Vs2019, how can I get the function names for my .def file?
I've thousand of functions and variables and I need a process to get them automatically

ADD.
The dumpbin /archivemembers seems not work, it's possible retrieve the list of mangled names after the build of the library? Where are those names?

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410284/list-functions-in-lib-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410284/list-functions-in-lib-on-windows)

Comment: This answer seemed to work for a static library: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/42167904/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42167904/487892)

Comment: Are you using  static library or  dynamic library?

Answer (score 2):

Answered here: [How to See the Contents of Windows library (*.lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305287/how-to-see-the-contents-of-windows-library-lib)

You can run either of these commands at the Developer command prompt:

```
dumpbin /archivemembers foo.lib
```

or

```
lib /list foo.lib
```

which will give you a full list of symbols in your library.

However maintaining this def file is quite tedious, and exporting *all* symbols is probably inadvisable. I suggest you look at the alternative method of using `__declspec(dllexport)` to [selectively export symbols from a DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport?view=msvc-170). You can define a macro which exports while building the DLL itself, and imports when building client code. By tagging the classes and functions in this way, each time you build, the exports will be regenerated and there is no separate `.def` file to maintain.

Comment: Where can I find the output of the command?

Comment: Both commands output text to the command line. You can pipe that to a text file

Comment: it gives me only a list of obj files

Comment: how can I pipe the output inside a text file? dumpbin /archivemembers foo.lib | file.txt  ?

Comment: I take my comments back. For a static library the output of either of these does not seem to be useful as it does not show the function names. Although both static libraries I tested had mainly classes.

Comment: `dumpbin /archivemembers foo.lib > file.txt`