# "unresolved external symbol"-error when linking a Cython extension against a C library on Windows

Tags: python, c, windows, visual-studio, cython

I am learning Cython and tried to run a simple example found here: [making C library callable](https://medium.com/@shamir.stav_83310/making-your-c-library-callable-from-python-by-wrapping-it-with-cython-b09db35012a3).

I used VS 2019 to create `mylib.lib` and `setup.py` to build the Cython-extension (for details and code see below), however the linker fails with error:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol hello

Yet when I ran `nm mylib.lib` that I found in other post I can see that the symbol `_hello` is present:

```
D:\Codes\git_folders\my_repository\Cython_test\lib>nm mylib.lib
...
Debug/examples.obj:
...
00000000 T _hello
...
```

What is going wrong?

---

**Code:**

`pyexamples.pyx`

```
cdef extern from "examples.h":
    void hello(const char *name)

def py_hello(name: bytes) -> None:
    hello(name)
```

`setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

examples_extension = Extension(
    name="pyexamples",
    sources=["pyexamples.pyx"],
    libraries=["mylib"],
    library_dirs=["lib"],
    include_dirs=["lib"]
)
setup(
    name="pyexamples",
    ext_modules=cythonize([examples_extension])
)
```

`examples.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "examples.h"

void hello(const char *name) {
    printf("hello %s\n", name);
}
```

`examples.h`

```
#ifndef EXAMPLES_H
#define EXAMPLES_H

void hello(const char *name);

#endif
```

However if I run this command,
 `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

I got this error.

```
running build_ext
building 'pyexamples' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ilib -IC:\Users\swsyo\anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\swsyo\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpyexamples.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\pyexamples.obj
pyexamples.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:lib /LIBPATH:C:\Users\swsyo\anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\swsyo\anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\ATLMFC\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" mylib.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_pyexamples build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\pyexamples.obj /OUT:D:\git_folders\my_repository\Cython_test\pyexamples.cp37-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\pyexamples.cp37-win_amd64.lib
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\pyexamples.cp37-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\pyexamples.cp37-win_amd64.exp
pyexamples.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol hello
D:\git_folders\my_repository\Cython_test\pyexamples.cp37-win_amd64.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

**More details:**

Based on comments below, I ran `dumpbin mylib.lib` command to see if `hello` function is in the libraries. Is this right way to do it ? I don't see the name `hello` in this summary though.

```
D:\Codes\git_folders\my_repository\Cython_test\lib>dumpbin mylib.lib
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.27.29111.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file mylib.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

  Summary

          E8 .chks64
         C94 .debug$S
          C8 .debug$T
         10A .drectve
           5 .msvcjmc
           A .rdata
           8 .rtc$IMZ
           8 .rtc$TMZ
         1B4 .text$mn
```

I also ran `nm mylib.lib` that I found in other post. You can see the `_hello` at the end of the summary.

```
D:\Codes\git_folders\my_repository\Cython_test\lib>nm mylib.lib

Debug\mylib.obj:
00000000 N .chks64
00000000 N .debug$S
00000000 N .debug$S
00000000 N .debug$S
00000000 N .debug$T
00000000 i .drectve
00000000 d .msvcjmc
00000000 r .rtc$IMZ
00000000 r .rtc$TMZ
00000000 t .text$mn
00000000 t .text$mn
         U @__CheckForDebuggerJustMyCode@4
010471b7 a @comp.id
80000391 a @feat.00
00000000 d __87B4E6C0_mylib@c
00000000 T __JustMyCode_Default
         U __RTC_CheckEsp
         U __RTC_InitBase
00000000 r __RTC_InitBase.rtc$IMZ
         U __RTC_Shutdown
00000000 r __RTC_Shutdown.rtc$TMZ
00000000 T _fnmylib

Debug/examples.obj:
00000000 N .chks64
00000000 N .debug$S
00000000 N .debug$S
00000000 N .debug$S
00000000 N .debug$S
00000000 N .debug$S
00000000 N .debug$S
00000000 N .debug$T
00000000 i .drectve
00000000 d .msvcjmc
00000000 r .rdata
00000000 r .rtc$IMZ
00000000 r .rtc$TMZ
00000000 t .text$mn
00000000 t .text$mn
00000000 t .text$mn
00000000 t .text$mn
00000000 t .text$mn
00000000 R ??_C@_09DEHHIH@hello?5?$CFs?6@
00000008 C ?_OptionsStorage@?1??__local_stdio_printf_options@@9@9
         U @__CheckForDebuggerJustMyCode@4
010471b7 a @comp.id
80000391 a @feat.00
00000000 T ___local_stdio_printf_options
00000001 d __101834BA_corecrt_wstdio@h
00000003 d __2F33A99E_examples@c
00000002 d __AD6A91B7_stdio@h
00000000 d __F66CEB67_corecrt_stdio_config@h
         U __imp____acrt_iob_func
         U __imp____stdio_common_vfprintf
00000000 T __JustMyCode_Default
         U __RTC_CheckEsp
         U __RTC_InitBase
00000000 r __RTC_InitBase.rtc$IMZ
         U __RTC_Shutdown
00000000 r __RTC_Shutdown.rtc$TMZ
00000000 T __vfprintf_l
00000000 T _hello
00000000 T _printf
```

After I rebuild the project for x64 system( I had to change "Active solution platform" to x64 in the Build > Configuration Manager), here is result of `dumpbin /symbols mylib.lib`. I can see the `hello` function in the summary.

[image]

Comment: It looks ok so far. The issue could be the library. How exactly did you build it? Is it by a chance a dll? You should check that the symbol hello is really present in the library.

Comment: @ead thanks for your comment. I made a static library using VS2019 and followed instruction (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=vs-2019) . I also made dll file just in case (different name). However the error is the same whether you use dll or lib. I put the library files in the folder name 'lib'.  What exactly do you mean by "check the symbol hello in really present in the library" ?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/305287/5769463 Maybe it was compiled as c++

Comment: @ead,  I edited my question above with adding results of checking library. How does one know the source file is complied as c++ ? Is it possible when we use *.c and *.h to be compiled as c++ in VS ?

Comment: @ead, Thank you very much. I successfully build the library for x64. I didn't know that VS default system architecture is x86, not x64. And finally the cython code is compiled as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuild the (static) library for x64.

The symbol in your library is called `_hello` and not `hello` as one would expect for a x64-build (your extension is built for 64bit as can be seen in the logs).

On x64, MSVC doesn't mangle names when compiling as C-code so the resulting symbol is simple - `hello`, but it does mangle C-names on x86 ([here documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names?view=vs-2019#FormatC), [here an example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cxPT17) on godbolt.org):

- `__cdecl`-calling convention (default for x86 if no special compile-flags are used) adds prefix `_` to the name which would lead to the symbol being called `_hello`.
- `__stdcall`-calling convention (if compiled with `/Gz` or the calling  convention is explicitly specified, i.e. `void __stdcall hello(char *)`) adds prefix `_` to the name and suffix `@` with the number of bytes in the parameter list, i.e. it would lead to `_hello@4`.

Thus, it becomes clear, that your library is built in 32bit and thus cannot be linked to a 64bit-dll.

---

Were the library a dll, the symbol's names would be slightly different. Calling

```
__declspec( dllimport ) void hello(char* a);
```

would lead to ([see live](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7MGbjx) on godbolt.org):

- `__imp__hello` (two underscores between `imp` and `hello`) for x86/32bit, i.e. prefix `__imp_` due to `declspec(dllimport)` and prefix `_` due to name mangling of `__cdecl` on x86.
- `__imp_hello` (one underscores between `imp` and `hello`) for x64/64bit, i.e. only prefix `__imp_` due to `declspec(dllimport)`.

---

There is also a more direct way to see, that the library is 32bit, by running:

```
dumpbin /headers mylibrary.lib
```

which would produce `machine (x86)` for 32bit build:

```
...
File Type: LIBRARY

FILE HEADER VALUES
             14C machine (x86)
...
```

but `machine (x64)` for 64bit build:

```
...
File Type: LIBRARY

FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64)
```

Furthermore, the MSVC-linker used to produce a warning when there is a machine-mismatch:

> mylibrary.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'X86' conflicts
> with target machine type 'x64'

Not sure why it wasn't present in your logs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I successfully compiled the cython code in VS 2019 as you suggested.

Comment: I encouter a problem when wrap a C++ exported .dll (not.lib) with Cython, is there any suggestions