# How do I resolve the linker error with 'cv::face::LBPHFaceRecognizer' in my OpenCV C++ code?

Tags: c++, opencv, unresolved-external

Unresolved External Source in OPENCV C++ Code with `cv::face::LBPHFaceRecognizer`.

I have OPENCV code which acts a trainer that takes a directory full of face images. I am running this on OpenCV `4.2.0` with the OPENCV contrib `4.2.0` library. I am also running this on the newest version of Visual Studios.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/face.hpp>
#include <opencv2/face/facerec.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::face;
using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

void assurePathExists(const string& path) {
    fs::create_directories(fs::path(path).parent_path());
}

int main() {
    Ptr<LBPHFaceRecognizer> recognizer = LBPHFaceRecognizer::create();
    CascadeClassifier detector;
    detector.load("C:/Users/781932/Downloads/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

    string datasetPath = "C:/Users/781932/Documents/STEMVisageVision";

    vector<Mat> faceSamples;
    vector<int> ids;

    vector<string> imagePaths;
    for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(datasetPath)) {
        if (entry.is_regular_file()) {
            imagePaths.push_back(entry.path().string());
        }
    }

    for (const auto& imagePath : imagePaths) {
        Mat img = imread(imagePath, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
        int id = stoi(fs::path(imagePath).stem().string().substr(1));

        vector<Rect> faces;
        detector.detectMultiScale(img, faces);

        for (const auto& face : faces) {
            faceSamples.push_back(img(face));
            ids.push_back(id);
        }
    }

    recognizer->train(faceSamples, ids);

    string trainerPath = "trainer/trainer.yml";
    assurePathExists(trainerPath);
    recognizer->write(trainerPath);

    return 0;
}
```

After cleaning and rebuilding the solution in VS, it is pretty apparent that the code itself is fine and has no errors. However, I am getting errors regarding the build.

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: 5_30_Trainer, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>5_30_Trainer.obj : error LNK2019: **unresolved external symbol "public: static struct cv::Ptr<class cv::face::LBPHFaceRecognizer> __cdecl cv::face::LBPHFaceRecognizer::create(int,int,int,int,double)" (?create@LBPHFaceRecognizer@face@cv@@SA?AU?$Ptr@VLBPHFaceRecognizer@face@cv@@@3@HHHHN@Z) referenced in function main**
1>C:\Users\781932\source\repos\5_30_Trainer\x64\Debug\5_30_Trainer.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "5_30_Trainer.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 9:21 AM and took 02.605 seconds ==========
```

There seems to be an issue with the the `cv::face::LBPHFaceRecognizer` class. I presume it's a linker issue, but I do have everything included in the project properties. What is the issue?

Comment: Are you sure you have included the library containing the `LBPHFaceRecognizer` class? Need to ask the obvious questions first.

Comment: `opencv_face420.lib`? I can't seem to find it in the contrib folder.

Comment: This moderator in this opencv forum thread says that the prebuilt opencv modules do not contain the face module and you need to build opencv yourself to get it: [https://forum.opencv.org/t/opencv-face-lbphfacerecognizer-error/5204/2](https://forum.opencv.org/t/opencv-face-lbphfacerecognizer-error/5204/2)

Comment: You could use the following answer to inspect the contents of the contrib lib you have to look for the face module: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/305444/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/305444/487892)