LNK2001 error and cannot see symbols in compiled library
I have a library that works well and I wanted to add additional functions.
Let's say I created a test.h:
class Test {
public:
Test();
void method1();
}

and test.cpp (not showing details here), both files have been added in Visual Studio solutions.
I can successfully compile the code into a new library (test.lib), however, when I compile another program that uses this library, I am having the error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ...method1... issue.`
Any ideas are greatly appreciated!
So I checked test.lib by using 7-zip, and I found that I cannot find the symbol method1 in 1.txt but I can see symbols defined in other source files, which I guess is the reason I saw link error.
I also checked the Build directory and found test.obj.

Lot of things could have gone wrong. More information is necessary, probably a [mre], to give you anything other than guesses at the problem.

So I checked test.lib by using 7-zip, Really? I didn't know that 7zip did that. I use the Microsoft tool called dumpbin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305287/how-to-see-the-contents-of-windows-library-lib

Any ideas are greatly appreciated! Like the first comment, I don't think there is enough information to tell without guessing.

Thank you @user4581301 and @drescherjm. I finally figured out it is because I did not add dllexport to functions: __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl Function1(void); https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport?view=msvc-170

Groovy. In that case I've formally closed the question as a duplicate. Hopefully future askers with a similar problem will find this and be led to an explanation of the solution.
